# How do I output a draw from a vote (In Java)?

Tags: java

I have no idea on how to output a draw from a vote any help on with this would be appreciated.

At the moment it will allow a user to select the amount of candidates and then the user inputs details.  Then the user will enter a vote, which is the candidate number, and type 999 to finish. The output will be the winner or  winners(draw)the candidates with details and votes and the amount of spolit votes that is votes not in the range declared at the start.

```
    int x;
    char highestChar = '1';
    char nextHighestChar = '1';
    String alpha = "123456";

            int largest=intVoteCount[1]; 
    int nextLargest=intVoteCount[1];
     for( x=1; x<=range; x++){ 
     if(intVoteCount[x]>largest){ 
     largest = intVoteCount[x]; 
     highestChar = alpha.charAt(intLoopCount);
     } 
     if(intVoteCount[x]>highestChar){ 
         nextLargest = intVoteCount[x]; 
         nextHighestChar = alpha.charAt(intLoopCount);
     } 
     }



        System.out.println("The winner is Candidate number "+ highestChar + " with " + largest + " votes.");
        System.out.println("The winner is Candidate number "+ nextHighestChar + " with " + nextLargest + " votes.");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("The Candidate votes are as follows.");

    for (intLoopCount = 1; intLoopCount <= range; intLoopCount++) {
        // Display all records.
        // New Instance

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Candidate " + intLoopCount + " "
                + strCandidateTitle[intLoopCount] + " "
                + strCandidateFirstname[intLoopCount] + " "
                + strCandidateSurname[intLoopCount] + " votes "
                + intVoteCount[intLoopCount]);


    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("Vote Count Spolit: " + intVoteCountSpolit);

}
```

}

Comment: You could start by defining what you mean by "draw".  And maybe why the candidate with the nextHighestChar is declared a winner...

Comment: Two candidates with the same amount of votes, a draw. nextHighestChar is what I tried to used to give me the second candidate if the vote count was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `largest == nextLargest` you have a draw, so print out an appropriate message saying so; otherwise, you have an explicit winner.